# Requested Resource not available - Servlets

Tags: servlets

This is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”ISO-8859-1” ?>
<web-app xmlns=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee”
     xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”
     xsi:schemaLocation=”http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd”
    version=”2.4”>
   <servlet> 
     <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>Ch1Servlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Chapter1 Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/Serv1</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

I have a Ch1Servlet.java file which looks like this:

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Ch1Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5778266762215708858L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        out.println("<html> " +
                "<body>" +
                "<h1 align=center>HF\'s Chapter1 Servlet</h1>" +
                 "<br>" + today + "</body>" + "</html>");
    }
}
```

I compiled the class, and placed it under WEB-INF/classes.

Here is my directory structure:

```
ch1
    WEB-INF
           web.xml
           classes
                  Ch1Servlet.class
```

When I try to access http://localhost:8080/ch1/Serv1 I get this:

description The requested resource (/ch1/Serv1) is not available.

Can anyone please provide some guidance, as to how overcome this problem?

Comment: What editor are you using for XML files? MS Word or something? Those curly quotes are syntactically invalid. Use a normal XML editor, or better yet, a normal IDE as it will automatically take care of validating code and compiling the necessary stuff and hotdeploying the changes to server.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? If you have used `Eclipse`, for instance, when creating a project, you have the option of changing the application context name. This way, although your project's name is `ch1`, you may have to type a different address in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Like as every other Java class which you would like to be publicitly visible to other classes which are by itself inside a package, you need to put the servlet class in a package. This way any decent container can find and load it. Packageless servlets only works in certain versions of Tomcat in combination with certain JDK versions. You don't want to be dependent on that.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, make sure that you're reading proper and up to date books/tutorials. Your `web.xml` (which is syntactically invalid by the way) specifies the old Servlet 2.4 version which was upgraded over 5 years ago already. I suggest to start at [our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). It contains some concrete Hello World examples and several excellent (and up to date) tutorials in footer.